# What is this green key icon on my hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, icons

On the company-owned laptop I use at work, there is a small green key icon which appears on top of the local `C:` drive.

[image: Green key icon]

This icon can be seen in **My Computer**:

[image: Key icon in My Computer]

And in the Windows Explorer sidebar:

[image: Key icon in sidebar]

**What is this green key icon and why is it on my C: drive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this green key icon and why is it on my C: drive?

It appears like your company is using [Sophos SafeGuard](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/safeguard-encryption.aspx) to manage the full disk encryption implemented by your system.  I based this on the following statement:

> One of my customers reports back that after initial encryption that
>   appear to be successful, the green key won't show up on boot partition
>   in Explorer.

It appears that description matches what appears in your screenshot.

Source: [Green Key won't show after initial FDE Encryption SG Enterprise 5.50](https://community.sophos.com/products/safeguard-encryption/f/sophos-safeguard-products/8776/green-key-won-t-show-after-initial-fde-encryption-sg-enterprise-5-50)

Comment: If your company is not using `Sophos SafeGuard Encryption` then you should ask your IT Administrator what the icon means.